# Which Barbarian ability and rune triggers Life on Hit (LoH) and for how much?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

**Rewording the initial question from a Sidearm only question to all the barbarian abilities**

Is there an overview that tells me which Barbarian ability profits from Life on Hit and if it is affected by diminishing returns (let's say if a Sidearm hit only heals partially what a normal hit does - or nothing at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kripp does explain it well but he does not have all the modifiers listed.

Here is a complete listing compiled by JarthMarder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evQu9.png

Comment: Most importantly, the answer to the question is buried toward the bottom of that spreadsheet.  Apparently Sidearm hits do NOT cause life on hit to proc.

Answer (score 3):

There are modifiers for life on hit. I think each hit of Cleave will only give around 75% of your life on hit (although you're likely to be hitting more than 1 mob, so you can get life back from each mob you hit). Frenzy is 100% of your life on hit, but I bet the sidearm axes don't get the full amount. Kripparrian has an excellent video on it on youtube here

Answer (score 1):

Each hit is individual. Also, the Life on Hit (I believe) all stacks and counts for all hits regardless of what weapon is doing the hitting. 
Sounds great for the changed monk skill-nerf.

I do not believe there is a diminishing return

You can also enable the setting to see the damage numbers fly in your options to see for yourself (as well as heals)

Comment: I'm not real clear on whether or not you're saying it counts.